# Some help needed to help the type inferring engine

Tags: scala, types

I've problems understanding where to put type informations in scala, and how to put it. Here I create several sequences of `Actor`s and I don't type them. Even if I had to, I wouldn't know which type of sequence `map` produces to give them the proper type.

Then later when the compiler yells at me because I'm trying to sum `Any`s, I've no idea where to begin filling in the gaps.

Here is my code, I tried to minimize it while still letting the necessary info available.

```
object Actors {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val array = randomArray(5)
        val master = new Master(array, 5)
        master.start
    }

    def randomArray(length: Int): Array[Int] = {
        val generator = new Random
        new Array[Int](length) map((_:Int) => generator nextInt)
    }
}

class Master(array: Array[Int], slavesNumber: Int) extends Actor {
    def act () {
        val slaves = (1 to slavesNumber).map(_ => new Slave)
        slaves.foreach(s => s.start)
        val futures = slaves.map(s => s !! Work(array))
        val results = awaitAll(3000, futures:_*)
        val res2 = results.flatMap(x => x)
        println((0 /: res2)(_+_))
    }
}

class Slave() extends Actor {
    def act () {
        Actor.loop {
            receive {
                case Work(slice) =>
                    reply((slice :\ 0)(_+_))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate too some good pointers towards comprehensive doc on the matter.

Comment: Which lines are you getting compile errors on? You probably need to provide type information to the output of `s !! Work(array)` using the `mapTo` transformation. Some documentation here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#ask-send-and-receive-future

Comment: the fold, it doesn't know which types are the arguments I feed to `(_+_)`. And I work with scala actors, not akka, don't know if it matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object that are passed between actors are not typed, actors have to filter the object themselves -- as you already do in the `Slave` actor. As you can see, `!!` is defined as

```
def !!(msg: Any): Future[Any]
```

so there is no type information in the returned `Future`. Probably the easiest solution is to replace the line `var res2 ..` with

```
val res2 = results collect {case Some(y:Int) => y}
```

this filters out just those `Some` results that are of type `Int`.